# Visualize multiple models in PCL

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to visualize **multiple** `.ply` point clouds (XYZRGB formatted) in a single view using PCL library.

This is what I have which visualizes a single model easily. But I need to have say 3 of the same model, but with different distances from my view (say the middle one be farther and left one be closer- zoomed out or zoomed in applied to them).

How can I do that? I had a huge trouble working with PCL to do this as the API is confusing. If you know of any better tools, preferably in languages other than C/C++, please also suggest.

```
    #include <iostream>
    //#include <unistd.h>
    #include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
    #include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
    #include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
    #include <pcl/console/parse.h>
    #include <pcl/common/transforms.h>
    #include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>


// Main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Fetch point cloud filename in arguments | Works with PLY files
    std::vector<int> filenames;

    filenames = pcl::console::parse_file_extension_argument(argc, argv, ".ply");

    // Load file | Works with PLY files
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr source_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>());

    pcl::io::loadPLYFile(argv[filenames[0]], *source_cloud);


    // Visualization 
    printf("\n Point cloud colors :\n"
        " \t white \t = \t original point cloud \n");

    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer(" Point Cloud Datsets Visualizer");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0); // Set background to a dark grey                            

                                                    // Define R,G,B colors for the point cloud 
    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(source_cloud);

    // We add the point cloud to the viewer and pass the color handler 
    viewer.addPointCloud(source_cloud, rgb, "original_cloud");
    viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 2, "original_cloud");

    //******************************
    std::vector<Point, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Point>> points = source_cloud->points;

    //******************************
    while (!viewer.wasStopped()) {   // Display the visualizer until the 'q' key is pressed
        viewer.spinOnce();

    }

    return 0;
} // End main()
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.danielgm.net/cc/

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Points

Comment: First one looks more like a software. But is there any example for three.js? JS looks good as long as it can process it efficiently.

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_points_sprites

Comment: First one is software not library but it has a lot of powerfull stuf including a visualizer where you can add multiple clouds and manually translate and rotate them.

Comment: three js is just webgl. The efficiency is quite good. Check http://www.potree.org. The bottleneck in js should be the file loading

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know of potree. I will look into them again.